# Adding values to a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv data file that contains data for recordID, duration, src, dst in each row.

I want to label each row(in a new column), with either a 0 or a 1 depending on the output of my algorithm.

I'm currently doing something like this, however, once outputting the DataFrame to a csv file, it deleted all the other, exiting columns.

Another issue is that this solution is extraordinarily slow. I thought of creating a simple array for array and then add that entire array as a new column, but I don't know how to do that either.

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv(f_path2, names=["record ID", "duration_", "src_bytes", "dst_bytes", "label"], header=None)
df2 = df2.dropna()
df2.head()

for source, dest, label in X_test_scaled:
    predict = kmeans.predict([[source, dest]])
    df2.at[total, 'label'] = predict # total as index
```

How do I do this correctly - actually update my existing file without rewriting the other columns, and faster?

Comment: What is `X_test_scaled` and how does it relate to your `df`?

Comment: It's my test dataset, in practice I will iterate over the entire data, however because the solution is slow I'm trying to edit only part of the csv file. What matters is that predict is a number 0 or 1 and f_path2 reads a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess since it is not really clear what your data looks like. But it seems that running `kmeans.predict` for the entire list at once might speed things up. You could then assign the list of predictions to a column in your dataframe:

```
df2['label'] = kmeans.predict([[source, dest] for source, dest, label in X_test_scaled])
```

Comment: This worked and was generally faster - I also used df.assign(label=array) to properly assign an entire array of values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer isn't precised - to provide solution - what I can conclude with that info:

You can use **apply()** with **loc**

In the loc you have access to every row - it's work like iterator of all rows.
Inside **predictorFunction** - based on another column you can return everything (in this case just execute your predictor)

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

```
def predictorFunction(currentRow):
   print(currentRow["record ID"])
   //return kmeans.predict([[currentRow["columnNameA"], currentRow["columnNameB"]]])

    
df2 = df['Predict'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```